# UFT 12.52 Browsers Support in Mac OS

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Can someone share any reference link where I can find HP UFT 12.52 Browser support details for Mac OS? I'm looking to understand whether UFT is compatible in Mac platform to automate FF, Safari & Chrome based web applications.

I've searched for it and got browser support matrix references, but no where I could see anything specific to Mac OS other than Safari.

Please help me to understand the HP UFT 12.5x's browsers' support on Mac. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, UFT supports testing on Mac, only Safari. If you want to test Chrome and Firefox, you can only do it on Windows.

Information on supported browsers version can be found in the Product Availability Matrix (PAM). Here is the link from the official HPE site for the latest UFT version: https://softwaresupport.hpe.com/group/softwaresupport/search-result/-/facetsearch/document/KM02046958

Answer (score 1):

QTP/UFT vs Safari Support Matrix

[Read This](http://www.learnqtp.com/uft-qtp-browser-support-matrix/)

Hope it helps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.